# Information about order of group with two elements of order $4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose I have a group $G$ of order $8$ with two elements $a$ and $b$ such that $|a|=|b|=4$. I also know that $a \notin \langle b\rangle$.

Can I conclude from this information that $\langle a, b\rangle=G$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We know that $\vert \langle a,b \rangle \vert$ divides $8$. Further, as $\{e, b, b^2, b^3, a\}\subseteq  \langle a,b \rangle $, we have $\vert \langle a,b \rangle \vert \geq 5$. Therefore, $\vert \langle a,b \rangle \vert = 8$, so $\langle a,b \rangle = G$.